# Clearing PlanningScene at beginning of script (moveit_commander)

Tags: moveit, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

i have a script where i add objects to the Planning Scene in MoveIt!. I want to clear all previously added objects at the beginning of the script, however, that does not work. What am i doing wrong? I also tried to iterate over all known objects but without success.

Is it because every time i start the script i create a new node and the objects of the "previous" node are not accessible?

```
rospy.init_node('planningscenenode', anonymous=True)
scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()

scene.remove_world_object()  # Does not work at the beginning
sleep(1)

co = CollisionObject()
co.id = 'plate'+str(0)
co.meshes = rospkg.RosPack().get_path('agilus')+"/meshes/" + "plate.stl"
ps = PoseStamped()
ps.pose.position.x = -0.6
ps.pose.position.y = -0.6
ps.pose.position.z = 0
ps.pose.orientation = Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(np.deg2rad(float(0)), np.deg2rad(float(0)), np.deg2rad(float(0))))

co.mesh_poses = ps
co.mesh_poses.header.frame_id = '/base_link'
scene.add_mesh(co.id, co.mesh_poses, co.meshes)
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281122/clearing-planningscene-at-beginning-of-script-(moveit_commander)/) by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-29**:
This doesn't answer your question, but why are you using the built-in `sleep` vs the `rospy` version?

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2018-01-29**:
Lack of knowledge. I will consider it in future code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a dirty fix

```
rospy.sleep(2)
scene.remove_world_object()
rospy.sleep(2)
```

There should be a better way right?

Edit: The problem could be related to https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/749

---

Originally posted by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) with karma: 56 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0